# Hypotheses Testing - Correlation vs. Regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, standardization, likert

I conducted a survey for my thesis and would like to begin with the hypotheses testing now. However, I am not sure what the correct process is - sorry if these are really basic questions!

Specifically, I have three variables:

- Customer Satisfaction
- Brand Attachment
- Purchase Intention

The first two represent means of multi-item scales, the latter is a singular Likert-type item  measured from 1-7. I hypothesized that Customer Satisfaction has a positive effect on Brand Attachment ($H_1$) and that Brand Attachment has a positive effect on Purchase Intention ($H_2$)(no mediation or moderation). Now, I plan to conduct a linear regression for $H_1$ and $H_2$.

- Do I need to run a correlation test before the linear regression?
- Do I report the unstandardized or standardized value for Beta resulting from the regression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My responses are slightly different from Peter's, but I feel they are nonetheless relevant.

> Do I need to run a correlation test before the linear regression?

As he said, you do not *need* to, but you really should always report them when possible. This enables future researchers to more easily run meta-analyses on your data, which often rely on effect sizes like Pearson correlations. If you get squirrely results from your regression that don't make sense in relation to your correlations, that could also be a sign something went wrong, so it doesn't hurt to know them. If you do include correlations, make sure to include confidence intervals and which method you employed (Pearson, Spearman, etc.).

> Do I report the unstandardized or standardized value for Beta resulting from the regression?

Both would be great (you can always put one in the manuscript and refer to the other in supplementary materials), but they provide different interpretations. Regressions which deal with raw estimates provide you with directly interpretable predictions and inference whereas standardized beta weights can give you information about the standard deviation differences in influence on the outcome.

Some commentary on Peter's response here:

> I'm a little worried that you got to this stage and are only now asking these questions. Your mentor should have made you figure this stuff out before starting. You should also have done a power analysis.

**I completely agree that this really should be known before you obtain data in the first place.** It is generally much better practice to come up with a sound theoretical model, design a statistical approach to answering the burning questions from that theory, and then go out and get data. You don't wanna be in a position where you spend thousands of dollars on research participants only to not know how to use them.

One last thing...I see you have Likert scale items that are supposed to approximate some kind of latent factor (such as customer satisfaction). It is absolutely imperative that you get reliability coefficients for these, as variables such as these can sometimes have very poor precision and may need to be amended if so. Many statistical programs have Cronbach's alpha coefficients that are straightforward to estimate. I would argue you should use omega coefficients, but that is pretty advanced and probably beyond the scope of this project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In that case, I will try to incorporate the correct method for the correlations in my analysis, too. Regarding the betas, I think I will mention just one in the body of the text, but put both in the appendix just to be safe.

Comment: I already calculated the Cronbach's Alpha's (all between 0.83 - 0.92) and also the McDonald's Omegas (similar values) so I assume that is okay. It was also kind of confusing, because a lot of the literature argued that you cannot make assumptions about reliability simply based on Cronbach - but since I saw it in former theses I just followed that lead.

Comment: I suppose its a learning experience either way. Glad the answer was helpful. If you feel Peter or I succeeded in answering your question, feel free to hit the checkmark next to either answer.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to CV.

For question A: No, you don't need to run correlation before regression, but you do need to check the assumptions of the model. Most of these checks are done after running the model.

For question B: Whatever your advisor or department wants you to do. Different fields have different standard ways to report, and your department may have their own requirements.

I'm a little worried that you got to this stage and are only now asking these questions. Your mentor should have made you figure this stuff out before starting. You should also have done a power analysis.

Comment: +1. This may be field-dependent, but it is more or less mandatory these days to report correlations with any statistical analysis involving more than one variable in psychology. For other reasons I outline in my answer, it doesn't hurt to add. I think your points about assumption checking and mentorship are really crucial.